# counting in oracle - what am I doing wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry for the Oracle-Noob question, but I'm having a problem with a query I'm trying to run and just can't seem to figure out how to write it.

If I break my query into two parts, I get the correct information for each.  See:

```
select   NVL (skill.category, 'Total:') "Skill Category",
         count (training.code) "# of Trainings"
from     skill join training on skill.code = training.code
group by rollup (skill.category);
```

returns:

```
Skill Category  # of Trainings
--------------- --------------
Database                     2
HR                           1
Leadership                   1
Printing                     1
Sales                        3
Web Design                   5
Total:                      13
```

Likewise, I get the following for the second query:

```
select NVL (skill.category, 'Total:') "Skill Category",
       count (project.code) "projects req training"
from   skill join project on skill.code = project.code
group by rollup (skill.category);

Skill Category  projects req training
--------------- ---------------------
Database                            2
Printing                            3
Web Design                          5
Total:                             10
```

However, when I try to combine these queries, my results get screwed up:

```
select NVL (skill.category, 'Total:') "Skill Category",
           count (training.code) "# of Trainings",
           count (project.code) "Projects Requiring Skill"
from skill join training on skill.code = training.code
           left join project on training.code = project.code
group by rollup (skill.category);

Skill Category  # of Trainings Projects Requiring Skill
--------------- -------------- ------------------------
Database                     4                        4
HR                           1                        0
Leadership                   1                        0
Printing                     3                        3
Sales                        3                        0
Web Design                  13                       13
Total:                      25                       20
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?  I greatly appreciate any help, and sorry if I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your joins a multiplying the data.  You have two 1-n relationships, between skills and trainings and between trainings and projects.  The result is multiplication of combinations.

The solution is to do the two summaries separately, and then combine them using join:

```
select st.*, "projects req training"
from (select NVL(skill.category, 'Total:') "Skill Category",
             count(training.code) "# of Trainings"
      from skill left outer join
           training
           on skill.code = training.code
      group by rollup (skill.category)
     ) st join
     (select NVL(skill.category, 'Total:') "Skill Category",
             count(project.code) "projects req training"
      from skill left outer join
           project
           on skill.code = project.code
      group by rollup (skill.category)
     ) sp
     on st."Skill Category" = sp."Skill Category"
```

In this version, I use `left outer join` in the subqueries, to be sure that each subquery returns all skills.  This allows me to use an `inner join` at the next level.  I've left the `rollup` in the subqueries, instead of doing an additional aggregation on the outside.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help with this! Your solution makes perfect sense, now that I'm looking at it. Thanks again!